# Headless Chrome breaks fDescribe and fIt for Protractor tests

Tags: angular, google-chrome, jasmine, protractor, headless

I've been running my Protractor tests on Chrome browser for my Angular 4 app. I want to use Headless Chrome but when I switch to Headless Chrome configurations, it prevents me from focusing specific tests when I run the tests via ng test. For example if I do "fDescribe" for a test case, it still runs ALL of my Protractor tests. Does anyone have any ideas what configuration change in Headless chrome prevents focus from working for fDescribe and fIt?

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
var phantomJSPath = require('phantomjs-prebuilt').path;


exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    // 'browserName': 'phantomjs',
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'loggingPrefs': { browser: "ALL" },
    'phantomjs.binary.path': phantomJSPath,
    'chromeOptions': {
      'args': ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', 'window-size=1400x800', 'disable-infobars']
    },
    shardTestFiles: true,
    //maxInstances: 3
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
    print: function () { }
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
      consolidateAll: true,
      savePath: './',
      filePrefix: 'xmlresults'
    }));
    var fs = require('fs-extra');

    fs.emptyDir('screenshots/', function (err) {
              console.log(err);
          });

          jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
              specDone: function(result) {
                  if (result.status == 'failed') {
                      browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
                          var browserName = caps.get('browserName');

                          browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                              var stream = fs.createWriteStream('screenshots/' + browserName + '-' + result.fullName.substring(0, 20) + '.png');
                              stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
                              stream.end();
                          });
                      });
                  }
              }
          });
  },

  //HTMLReport called once tests are finished 
  onComplete: function () {
    var browserName, browserVersion;
    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();

    capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
      browserName = caps.get('browserName');
      browserVersion = caps.get('version');

      var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter');

      testConfig = {
        reportTitle: 'Query Tool e2e Test Execution Report',
        outputPath: './',
        screenshotPath: './screenshots',
        testBrowser: browserName,
        browserVersion: browserVersion,
        modifiedSuiteName: false,
        screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true
      };
      new HTMLReport().from('./xmlresults.xml', testConfig);
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`--headless` is not breaking focusing, the issue is in `shardTestFiles: true`, which is not compatible with jasmine `fdescribe()` `fit()`.

Check here:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1357